# Dynamic paths in NextJS with constraints

Tags: next.js

I want to make dynamic path for `/app/books/[name]` and `/app/articles/[name]` in NextJS. I want to avoid code duplication because both of these websites will look very similar and I wanted to do sth like this `/app/[book|article]/[name]/page.tsx` and then in  `page.tsx` I could use `Page({params}: {params: {bookOrArticle: "book" | "article", name: string})` and use `bookOrArticle` to distinguish between `/app/books/` and `/app/articles/` paths. How can I do that in NextJS?

Comment: you can just simply have `/app/[model]/[name]` and in the `page.tsx` you can check the params. if the model's value is not one of those models, then return 404: `if (!["books", "articles"].includes(params.model)) { notFound() }`